# How to declare a global array within a function without the -g option?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am writing a shell script to read key values within a config file and dynamically creating arrays based upon their name. Consider the following statement within a shell function:

```
declare "${fruit[i]}}"[x]=${var}
```

This works perfectly and assigns the array element correctly however, when used inside a function this is array is not global. I know later versions of bash support the -g option which declares the variable/array as global but I am using an older version of bash (working with what I have) which does not support this option.

How can I emulate the declare -g option here in order to make my array global? I have tried playing about with eval and readonly but I am not having any luck.

**EDIT:**
I'd like to also mention that the elements I am assigning to the dynamic arrays contain spaces as well. This was what was breaking my eval command when I was trying that.

Comment: The `eval` options are not as safe as `-g`; to get the best of both worlds you can `declare -g x=... 2>/dev/null || x=...` to use the eval or other technique only when `-g` isn't available. Be sure that your `declare` expression can't fail in any other way, though, or the failure will be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by gniourf_gniourf, you can use `printf -v` (in `bash` 4.1 or later)

```
printf -v "${fruit[i]}[x]" "%s" "$var"
```

or `read`

```
read "${fruit[i]}[x]" <<< "$var"
```

<strike>You probably just need to make sure the expression passed to `eval` contains appropriate quotes.</strike>

```
$ fruit=(apple pear orange)
$ f () { eval "${fruit[$1]}[$2]=\"$3\""; }
$ f 0 2 'hi there'  # apple[2]='hi there'
$ declare -p apple
declare -a apple='([2]="hi there")'
```

It should go without saying that this isn't recommended, given the risk for arbitrary code execution.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on quotes at all here. Think of `f 0 2 '"; ls -al #'`. The proper way to use `eval` in this case is: `f() { var=$3 eval "${fruit[$1]}[$2]"='$var'; }`, passing `var` as environment variable to `eval` and with single quotes to protect the expansion `$var`, so that what's really `eval`'d is `apple[2]=$var`. Or, equivalently, `f() { var=$3 eval "${fruit[$1]}[$2]=\$var"; }`.

Comment: Good point. My *real* recommendation is to not do this at all. `printf '%q'` is probably needed here somewhere as well.

Comment: The `eval`-with-environment-variable is rather safe (in fact, completely safe wrt the right hand side)! (and portable) ((well, portable when not using arrays, of course)). Other options: use `printf` with `-v` (that's a good one!) or even `read`.

Comment: Ugh, both of those are far better than using `eval`. Why didn't I post that instead?

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback. Won't be at the computer until Friday so I'll let you know how things go then.

Comment: Thank you, the `read` command worked perfectly. The `printf -v` didn't work however and looking online it appears there is a documented bash bug: "printf -v doesn't allow array assignment"

Comment: Ah, `printf -v` requires `bash` 4.1 to assign to arrays.